# Sum of scores on three dice

Tags: probability

A red die, a green die and a black die are thrown. Denote a sample point of this random experiment by ($a_r,a_g,a_b$) where $a_r$ is the score on the red die, $a_g$ is the score on the green die and so on. Each sample point is equally likely to occur.

1) Probability of the sum of scores is 11

2) Probability at least two of the scores are the same

So what I have done thus far is calculated size of the sample space ($6^3$) which is 216. But that is about as far as I have achieved since I am not sure how to find the probability that the sum of scores is 11 (other than manual work which isn't going to be useful really).

Answer (score 1):

1) Manual work *is* useful and fasible here. Note that $11=6+a+(5-a)$ with $a\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $11=5+a+(6-a)$ with $a\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $11=4+a+(7-a)$ with $a\in\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ and so on.

2) First compute the probability that all scores differ.

Comment: 2.b) ... and then use the fact that P(no two scores are the same) + P(two or more scores are the same) = 1.

Answer (score 1):

the_candyman is incorrect on #1. It is true that (1,4,6) has 6 permutations, but (3,4,4) only has 3. There are 3 with 6 permutations and 3 with 3; that's 27 alltogether. 27/216 = 1/8.

Comment: I seen this as well. Thank you both for the help.

Comment: @Balazs Rau. good point. Then also (3,5,5) and (1,5,5) has 3 permutations.

Comment: @the_candyman: like I said, 3 of the possibilities have 3 permutations and the other 3 have 6.

Answer (score 0):

1) $11$ can be achieved with the following combination:
$(1,4,6),(2,3,6),(1,5,5),(2,4,5),(3,3,5), (3, 4, 4)$
Clearly, given a combination you can have three different situation. For example:
$$a_r=1, a_g=4, a_b=6; a_r=1, a_g=4, a_b=6; a_r=4, a_g=1, a_b=6; a_r=4, a_g=6, a_b=1; a_r=6, a_g=1, a_b=4; a_r=6, a_g=4, a_b=1$$
So, for each combination, you can have $6$ permutation. Given that 
$$\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}$$
is the probability to have one combination, then
$$6\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}$$
is the probability to have one of the permutation. Finally, since combination are $6$, then
$$6 \cdot 6\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$$
2) If you have two "1", and the third die is different from "1", then the probability is 
$$\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6} = \frac{5}{216}$$
Clearly you can have $a_r=a_g=1\neq a_b$, or $a_r=a_b=1\neq a_g$, or $a_g=a_b=1\neq a_r$. So you have to multiply the above probability by $3$. Finally, since you have $6$ number, you have to multiply by $6$ (we have considered only the case "1"). At the end you have:
$$3 \cdot 6 \cdot \frac{5}{216} = \frac{90}{216}$$
At this point, you have to sum to this the probability that $a_r=a_g=a_b$ which is $$6 \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6} = \frac{6}{216}$$
and then
$$ \frac{90}{216} + \frac{6}{216} =  \frac{96}{216} = \frac{4}{9}$$

Comment: Isn't (4, 4, 3) a possible combination as well?

Comment: yeah, your right...

Comment: I've corrected it! thanx